# widget displaying two pane listbox in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, ttk

there is some pre-cooked widget in tkinter (or ttk) able to display two listboxes side by side?

It is pretty usual to find them in cases such as *add/remove option on the right pane from the list of possible options in the left pane*, but I cannot find any example.

(not so hard to do it myself, but if there's a ready made widget it's better...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no pre-made widget to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tkinter.ttk.Treeview, but it is slightly different and requires you to have a column header label.